# max(), group by and order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, max

I have following SQL statement.

```
    SELECT t.client_id,max(t.points) AS "max" FROM sessions GROUP BY t.client_id;
```

It simply lists client id's with maximum amount of points they've achieved. Now I want to sort the results by max(t.points). Normally I would use ORDER BY, but I have no idea how to use it with groups. I know using value from SELECT list is prohibited in following clauses, so adding ORDER BY max at the end of query won't work.

How can I sort those results after grouping, then?

Best regards

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT t.client_id, max(t.points) AS "max" 
FROM sessions t
GROUP BY t.client_id 
order by max(t.points) desc
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I just figured out that points column was in fact character varying(), so I used to_number function and now it works.

Comment: Why don't you use the correct datatype in your table? That will speed up the query as well, create an index on that column and the query will be faster. An index on a varchar won't work when you need a number.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't created this table and have no rights to change it's structure. Just writing some software for existing CRM. I'm going to tell administrator to change that.

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite correct that values from the `SELECT` list are prohibited in following clauses.  In fact, `ORDER BY` is logically processed after the `SELECT` list and can refer to `SELECT` list result names (in contrast with `GROUP BY`).  So the normal way to write your query would be

```
SELECT t.client_id, max(t.points) AS "max"
    FROM sessions
    GROUP BY t.client_id
    ORDER BY max;
```

This way of expressing it is SQL-92 and should be very portable.  The other way to do it is by column number, e.g.,

```
    ORDER BY 2;
```

These are the only two ways to do this in SQL-92.

SQL:1999 and later also allow referring to arbitrary expressions in the sort list, so you could just do `ORDER BY max(t.points)`, but that's clearly more cumbersome, and possibly less portable.  The ordering by column number was removed in SQL:1999, so it's technically no longer standard, but probably still widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged as **Postgres**: Postgres allows a *non-standard* `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` column number. So you could have

```
SELECT t.client_id, max(t.points) AS "max" 
FROM sessions t
GROUP BY 1 
order by 2 desc
```

After parsing, this is identical to RedFilter’s solution.