# Sorting on child model's price attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I have 2 models: `Product` and `Sku`, where a `Product` has many `Sku`s

I'm trying to come up with a search & sort interface, and I have filters working for product category, etc.  My question is how to return the ranked **products** based on the price of the skus.

For example:

```
product | id: 1
product | id: 2
product | id: 3

# Skus for Product 1
sku | id: 1, product_id: 1, price: 1111
sku | id: 5, product_id: 1, price: 5555
sku | id: 9, product_id: 1, price: 9999

# Skus for Product 2
sku | id: 2, product_id: 2, price: 2222
sku | id: 3, product_id: 2, price: 3333
sku | id: 4, product_id: 2, price: 4444

# Skus for Product 3
sku | id: 6, product_id: 3, price: 6666
sku | id: 7, product_id: 3, price: 7777
sku | id: 8, product_id: 3, price: 8888
```

A sort by "price low to high" should return:

```
[ product 1, product 2, product 3 ]
```

while "price high to low" should return:

```
[ product 1, product 3, product 2 ]
```

This is simple enough for 3 products, but I'm having trouble figuring out pagination (i.e. thousands of products, with consistent offsets etc).

It seems like it should be some combination of `group by` and searching by `sku` followed by finding the corresponding `product`.  Is there a simple way to do this type of ordering in Postgres?

**Update**

This is different than the referenced "duplicate".  I have 2 models here, and want to sort one model based on the values of its children.  The referenced duplicate has only 1 model.

For edge cases: a "tie" on sku price could be dealt with however (e.g. `id asc` for skus), as long as it's consistent. Products do not have values to order, and there are no duplicate products in the DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [max(), group by and order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298703/max-group-by-and-order-by)

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298703/max-group-by-and-order-by. JOIN Product to Sku, then ORDER BY MAX(Sku.price).

Comment: Is that JSON in the sku table? JSON is a bad choice there since sku is well structured data.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto no, not using JSON. That's just how I was showing information.  I've edited to remove confusion

Comment: this is missing a lot.  How are edge cases dealt with (eg if the min price of two sku are the same).  What are you doing to get the orders... are you ordering the min values of each product or are you ordering the values and then removing duplicates of the product?

Comment: @Hogan I've added above.  If price of 2 skus is the same, then we can employ some kind of tie-breaker, similar to if we were just sorting the skus themselves.  Products do not have values to order, and there are no duplicate products in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order by the min value of each price range:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
  SELECT p.id, min(s.price) as min_price
  FROM product p
  JOIN sku s on p.id = s.product_id
  GROUP BY p.id
) x
ORDER BY min_price ASC
```

---

You probably want this

```
SELECT p.productid
from (
  SELECT p.productid, s.price,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.productid, ORDER BY s.price ASC) as rn
  from product p
  JOIN sku s on p.id = s.product_id
) x
where rn = 1
```

and this

```
SELECT p.productid
from (
  SELECT p.productid, s.price,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.productid, ORDER BY s.price DESC) as rn
  from product p
  join sku s on p.id = s.product_id
) x
where rn = 1
```

But as I said I'm still not sure if you are ordering by price and removing dup productids (as this is) or if you want to order by the min value and max value of each products price range (as the "duplicate" does).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I want to order by the min value of each product's price range

Comment: The first query works great (with `id` in place of `productid`).  Thanks!